# When to hide a sidenav

Tags: gui-design, responsive-design, best-practice, sidebar

I have in my app a sidenav which is by default visible. Now I got a feedback from users, that in lower resolutions (mobile, tablets) the sidenav covers a lot of space from the app. My question is: on which resolution should I hide the sidenav?

Comment: How wide is your sidenav? If its just an icon list like that of the Twitter redesign, then it is thin of enough to be left alone (though even that depends if your content needs more breathing space for reading or viewing images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a web app or a mobile app? Either way, on mobile phones in portrait orientation it is abnormal and inconsiderate to reserve so much screen real estate for a fixed menu. In landscape it might work, but generally and as James Coyle says, a side-navigation can typically be hidden from view with a toggle.

Tabs and Bottom Navigation work well in portrait orientation on mobile phones because there they take up much less screen realestate than a fixed side-navigation.

Typically in Android, a tablet device typically falls into the `sw600dp` classification (or you may prefer `sw720dp`), where the device's smallest width is greater than or equal to 600dp. So I suggest you change the sidenav to one that can be toggled closed or open then make it so it is always open on tablets.

Answer (score 1):

Id generally say if the side nav is more than a third of the screen width it should be toggleable or modal. It really depends on the content of your app and how important the navigation is.